# how to make nullable = true, When using withcolumn to create a binary column of 1 and 0,

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

this is the code that I'm using

```
dfn = df.withColumn("id",F.when(F.col("number1") > F.col("number2"), 1 ).otherwise(0))
```

#### Problem:

it returns `integerType` and `nullable = false`.

#### Goal:

I want it `doubleType` and `nullable = true`

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: With your current query, this column will never be null, so why do you need `nullable = true`? For `doubleType` just cast the value returned by : `when(...).otherwise(...).cast("double")`

Comment: I was having some trouble to run VectorAssembler but I Already found the problem. thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType

dfn = df.withColumn("id",(F.when(F.col("number1") > F.col("number2"), 1 ).otherwise(0)).cast(DoubleType()))
dfn = dfn.withColumn("id", F.when(F.col("id").isNotNull(), F.col("id")).otherwise(F.lit(None)))

dfn.printSchema()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer although it returns ```doubleType``` it is still ```nullable = false```

Comment: I think that should do the trick if you can't rebuild the original df